# Cauchy riemann equations - determine a conclusion

Tags: complex-numbers

$$(x^2+y^2)+2ixy$$

I'm supposed to apply the Cauchy Riemann equations to the above and figure out what conclusions can be made. Below is what I've ended up with after applying the equations:

$$u_x=2x$$
$$v_y=2x$$
$$u_y=2y$$
$$-v_x=-2y$$

Because $2y \neq-2y$, I think I can say that $f'(z)$ does not exist at any point. However, I feel that the application of these equations does not necessarily speak about the entire function. I thought the point of the C-R equations are to help find a derivative of $f(z)$ at a particular point, no?

Comment: Can you find a point $(x, y)$ whede CR does hold?

Comment: @Kaster $(0,0)$ would be a fine guess I think.

Comment: And what about point $(1, 0)$ or $(2, 0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C-R equations hold exactly when $2y = -2y$, i.e., whenever $y = 0$. Thus $f$ is complex-differentiable precisely on the real line $\{x + 0i \in \mathbb{C}\ \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Why would that precisely be a line though? Can't we imagine a function that passes through the x-axis twice? It would still mean the same thing to say that in that function that passes through the x-axis twice the derivative does not exist when $y=0$.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat it's a line because when you vary $x$ only and keep $y = 0$ you get, well, a line.

Comment: @Kaster Oh geez....yea idk what I was thinking lol! You're right.